# Function type specialisation in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, ghc, generic-programming

I have a function that has type `Read a => String -> a`, is it possible to have another function with the same name that does things differently when `a` is for example `String`?  Are there any GHC extensions that allow this?

Something like:

```
f :: Read a => String -> a
f = read

f :: String -> String
f = id
```

Comment: If you're just concerned about performance, these kind of things should get optimized out by the compiler.

Comment: I'm not concerned about performance, I want a version of `read` that doesn't require quotation marks around strings, but works as normal `read` for everything else.

Comment: The question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870962/haskell-making-a-superclass-of-num/ addresses exactly the same problem; some answers there may be useful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Haskell, this kind of function overloading (ad-hoc polymorphism) is accomplished by using type classes, not by binding the same name under multiple types.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, TypeSynonymInstances #-}

class F a where f :: String -> a

instance F String where f = id
instance F Int where f = read
instance F Char where f = read
instance F Float where f = read
-- etc.
```

Now, `f` can operate on any type for which an instance of `F` has been declared.

Unfortunately, you can't get away with the following:

```
instance Read a => F a where f = read
```

Perhaps unintuitively, this does *not* declare an instance of `F` only for types which have an instance of `Read`. Because GHC resolves instances using only the head of the instance declaration (the part to the right of the `=>`), this actually declares all types `a` to be instances of `F`, but makes it a type error to call `f` on anything which is not also an instance of `Read`.

It will compile if you enable the `UndecidableInstances` extension, but this just leads to other problems. It's a rabbit hole you don't really want to venture down.

Instead, you should declare an instance of `F` for each individual type you intend `f` to operate on. This isn't very burdensome for a simple class like this one, but if you use a recent version of GHC, you can use the following to make it slightly easier:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}

class F a where f :: String -> a
                default f :: Read a => String -> a
                f = read
```

Now, for any type which is an instance of `Read`, you may declare its instance of `F` without having to provide the implementation of `f` explicitly:

```
instance F Int
instance F Char
instance F Float
-- etc.
```

For any types *without* instances of `Read`, you'll still have to write an explicit implementation for `f`.

Answer (score 4):

I got it to work, but I had to turn on a bunch of questionable language options:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances #-}

class SpecialRead a where
  specialRead :: String -> a

instance Read a => SpecialRead a where
  specialRead = read

instance SpecialRead String where
  specialRead = id

main = do
    print (specialRead "10" :: Int)
    print (specialRead "10" :: String)
```

Comment: `FlexibleInstances` and `TypeSynonymInstances` are uncontroversial; they just relax some restrictions imposed by the Haskell standard, but aren't anything to worry about. `UndecidableInstances` and `OverlappingInstances` are dangerous territory, however, and should generally be avoided unless you know what you're doing.